# Jumping a car and attaching cables after starting donor car's engine

Tags: battery, battery-drain, jump-start

I was jumping my friend's car today in a place with no cell phone reception.

He argued that the jumper cables should be attached *after* starting the donor car's engine.  He said that it would decrease the risk of inadvertently depleting the donor car's battery.  I thought this argument made sense.

We did so, and jumping the car was ultimately a success.

I came home tonight, and read that the jumper cables should have been attached first, before starting the donor car.

I am wondering: **is there any risk of a donor car's battery being drained before starting the engine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...

But you also run the risk of damaging the donor car’s alternator.

So, the method I use is to connect the cables and then start the donor car and run at 2000rev/min for 5 to 10 minutes. This puts some charge into the other battery. Then turn off the donor engine and start the other car.

People will say “but I have always run the engine on the donor car when starting...”

Fine, I have replaced alternators damaged due to the energy surge many times. The owner always says “it stopped charging just after jumping another car”. They were never happy about what a 2 minute kindness cost them...

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike!  Out of curiosity, do you happen to have any sources on the potential alternator damage?  Or just personal experience/what you've seen?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer if you check my profile - I was a vehicle electrician... worked on **so** many different cars, vans, trucks, buses, tractors, stationary engines... sometimes people have relevant experience.

Comment: Yes, thank you again, agreed.  I was just curious, because I try to compensate for my lack of experience with reading